Discretizing Caputo Derivative
Have a look at the following article (Eqn 7), it is given an approximation that
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \left.\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \int_0^\tau \frac{\partial u(x, \eta)}{\partial \eta}(\tau-\eta)^{-\alpha} d \eta\right|_{\substack{x=x_i \\
\tau=\tau_{k+1}}} \\
& = \frac{1}{\Gamma(2-\alpha)} \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{u\left(x_i, \tau_{k+1-j}\right)-u\left(x_i, \tau_{k-j}\right)}{\Delta t^\alpha}\cdot \left[(j+1)^{1-\alpha}-j^{1-\alpha}\right]+O\left(\Delta t^{2-\alpha}\right) \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
My concerns:
i. I can see that the first derivative in the integrand has been approximated by a forward Euler though I am confused with the indices $k-j+1 ~\&~ k-j$.
ii. A factor $\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$ has been come out of the approximation while handling the factor $(\tau-\eta)d \eta$ and results in the factor $\frac{\left[(j+1)^{1-\alpha}-j^{1-\alpha}\right]}{\Delta t^{\alpha -1}}$.
iii. Why ROC is $2-\alpha$?
How can I utilize the above approximation to deal with the integral $$\left.\int_0^\tau \frac{\partial^2 u(x, \eta)}{\partial \eta^2}(\tau-\eta)^{1-\alpha} d \eta\right|_{\substack{x=x_i \\
\tau=\tau_{k+1}}}.$$
Thanks in advance.
